# How do arbitrary floating point values compare to infinity?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point

Basically i want to search for the smallest (positive) value from a bunch of values and need a default value to compare to the first one. The naïve assumption would be, they *always* compare "less than" (except NaNs, but let's not consider those) but I'm not quite sure.

I'm using the `float` type and I think it can safely be assumed that my target hardware implements a infinity value.

Here's some example code:

```
auto leastValue = std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();
for (auto i = something.begin(), e = something.end(); i != e; ++i)
{
  auto value = (*i)->GetValue();
  if (value < leastValue)
  {
    leastValue = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could also just use the first value as your initial value. It'll most likely still work if you put in infinity; I'm just pointing out that you don't actually *need* to use a special inital value.

Comment: With pulling `i` out of the loop and adding an additional check for an empty collection, I could. But would'nt that render the question useless? ;)

Comment: Use `std::min_element` and let it worry about stuff like that?

Comment: when you are not searching for the minimum of your sequence, but for the minimum of a function (in the _mathematical_ sense) of your sequence elements, both suggestions are awkward - using the first value means writing the code/call for the function twice, and min_element doesn't work for that.

Comment: @kiw: Well, you might just not have considered that possibility - that sort of thing happens more often than one might expect. :)

Comment: etarion is right: Duplicate code is not a good idea (at least of the hand-written sort). With `min_element` I had to call `GetValue` again as I need both the sequence element _and_ `value` and that function is rather expensive.  
@Michael Madsen: I really didn't :o

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For IEEE 754 floats, except NaN and infinity, everything is less than infinity. Chances are you'll have those on your platform. If you're paranoid, check with `numeric_limits<float>::is_iec559`. If your platform happens to be not conforming, use `numeric_limits<float>::max()`; if your sequence is nonempty, it will not give you a wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

I support Michael Madsen comment: You don't need an infinite value for this test,

Store the first value of your bunch in a variable and then start your testing with the second value of the bunch. (and it will even save you one test :P)

Answer (score 0):

I think this depends on what behaviour you expect if the sequence is empty. If you want infinity your implementation is fine, otherwise you should use the first value.

```
auto i = something.begin();
auto e = semething.end();
if (i == e)
  throw std::exception("empty sequence");

auto leastValue = (*i)->GetValue();

for (++i; i != e; ++i)
{
  auto value = (*i)->GetValue();
  if (value < leastValue)
  {
    leastValue = value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Infinity is in fact the right answer if the sequence is empty. It can also be the right answer if the sequence is not empty, because not all elementy do yield a value (which was not in my example code).