# What is the correct constant to use when comparing with the Minimal Single Number in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

In a loop like this:

```
cur := -999999; // represent a minimal possible value hold by a Single type
while ... do
begin
  if some_value > cur then
     cur := some_value;
end;
```

There is MaxSingle/NegInfinitydefined in System.Math

```
  MaxSingle   =  340282346638528859811704183484516925440.0;
  NegInfinity = -1.0 / 0.0;
```

So should I use  **-MaxSingle** or   **NegInfinity** in this case?

Comment: `cur := cur.MinValue;` also works fine. See [SysUtils.TSingleHelper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.TSingleHelper).

Comment: Use an Boolean flag to record if `cur` already is assigned or not. Don't rely on magical values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to find the largest value in a list.

If your values are in an array, just use the library function `MaxValue()`. (If you look at the implementation of `MaxValue`, you'll see that it takes the first value in the array as the starting point.)

If you must implement it yourself, use `-MaxSingle` as the starting value, which is approximately -3.40e38. This is the most negative value that can be represented in a `Single`.

Special values like `Infinity` and `NaN` have special rules in comparisons, so I would avoid these unless you are sure about what those rules are. (See also [How do arbitrary floating point values compare to infinity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4675601/how-do-arbitrary-floating-point-values-compare-to-infinity). In fact, it seems `NegInfinity` would work OK.)

It might help to understand the range of values that can be represented by a Single. In order, most negative to most positive, they are:

> NegInfinity
>
> -MaxSingle .. -MinSingle
>
> 0
>
> MinSingle .. MaxSingle
>
> Infinity

Comment: Thanks. I will use -MaxSingle instead of Infinity because I am not sure does using Infinity have an impact on the performance